# About Timestamp in Geotagging

Tags: gps, geotag

I'm on my reasearch for GPS and sensors integration. I've just wondered that to integrate between GPS and camera you need time offset synchronize which called as a timestamp.

But how  does software calculate those time offset estimate automatically? (I use APM - Mission Planner for software and GPS module on arduino for hardware), I have googled it but I haven't found what I want.

Because I'm working in "accuracy and precision quality" of integrated sensors, what I want to find is like "Is there any fluence that take to the distance among the sensors as the affect of time offset?" or "let say there is, how can I calculate that in concrete way? Like if the time offset goes one second, how much the distance lack (in meters)".

Can anyone give me some explanation about this?

Or do you have any paper or article about it?

Or maybe have a right keyword for google search?

Comment: I'm not really following the question. A timestamp is a attribute/piece of data that records the time of a record. To synchronize the timestamps between two different sources, you need the differential correction - that is, source A says 2:13:45 and source B says 2:13:41, a difference of 0:00:04. The correction may be constant, or if the clocks aren't running at the same rate it might vary - kind of depends on what accuracy and precision you're looking at. I can't think of any way software would do it "automatically" unless given key points (same event in both streams) to match and calc from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris, I really appreciate it. Okay, lets say We have 4 minutes time offset. What is the different if we have 3 minutes offset, or maybe more than 4 minutes, 5 minutes or 6 minutes? why we need time correction exactly?

Comment: That depends on what you're doing with it. If your (separate) GPS and camera record different times for the same event and you later try to match the two sets of data *by time*, GPS would say you were in front of house X while the picture would be of house Z (and distance for one second varies with speed). If all devices are running off the same clock it's not an issue - for example a computer is recording the inputs from multiple external sensors, but since the *computer* is doing the recording everything should be sync'd to its clock regardless of if the external sensors have their own.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, the devices are not running of the same clock, and it's affect to the point of exposure where the camera takes a picture, so we need the time correction. I want to know how far the distance offset among its exact position. I want to know how far it would be if we have 1 second time offset from the point of exposure itself (in meters)?

Comment: I want to know exactly the distance offset in meters in any speed circumstances including without speed at all. Furthermore, the different effects between any GPS devices such as handheld, module, or geodetic one and its different frequencies

Comment: Well again, that depends on speed. Traveling at 1m/s? It's 1m. 5m/s? 5m. You're probably not going to have a *constant* differential, because you probably can't keep your speed (assuming a UAV here) truly constant. The faster you're going, the greater the error. In theory the time between trigger and exposure will be constant, but the distance traveled won't. Altitude would also play a role - the lower you are the more pronounced an error. Just manually setting the two clocks as close as possible might be sufficient.

Comment: If the devices are not moving, it wouldn't be an error, would them? for example, I'm holding my GPS handheld on my left hand and camera with the right one and I'm not moving or stand still, and I have 5 minutes time offset, it wouldn't be distance offset? where did you find the theory about it? can you give me some link about this? or articles maybe? Instead, I have read about this topic, but they used kalman filtering methods to estimate the error, yeah, unfortunately I don't understand about it

Comment: No, there wouldn't be any positional error (0m/s, 0m) - distance implies movement and therefore speed. But that only applies to location, not time (recall from earlier I said if matching two sources *by time*). Consider the sync between an audio track and video track in a movie, two separate data streams. Again, you'd need a known event to mark in the two streams to sync them. I'm afraid I can't offer much more; what I've mentioned is just from general knowledge, not specific theories or articles. It sounds like you might be wanting info on signals processing or statistics.

Comment: I see, but how do softwares plot the photos in the map or transform it into geotagg photo with only log data from GPS and its time offset estimate. You said software wouldn't do it "automatically" unless it's given a key points (same event in both streams) to match and calc from. I'm just curious what will happen if I fill the different time offset far from it's actual value ( I don't have the dataset now, so I can't try it)